# Git branches and auto integration

Tags: git

my question is regarding git branches and auto integration between them. We have a master branch and a patch branch. Sometimes, when we fix a bug in a patch branch, we forget to push that fix to the master branch. Since this is manual, it's getting hard to track. Is there a way where we can set up some triggers to push any change made to a patch branch automatically into the master branch? Much like perforce's auto integrations?

Comment: Then how about conflict handling?

Comment: If you're going to automatically merge changes from one branch to another, why use a branch at all?

Comment: @Schwern Maybe master contains more recent development that isn't supposed to be in the patch branch. If you think of *patch* branch as a *release* branch, the requirement is not that unreasonable. master could contain new features and fixes for existing releases must also be part of future releases.

Answer (score 0):

I would *not* recommend auto-integration.  It effectively negates the purpose of branches.  You might as well just commit hot fixes straight to master.

What I would instead recommend is to have a tool for viewing the state of integration.  It can be as simple as having a tool which runs `git branch --no-merged master` periodically.

Also, have a single explicit branch for hot-fixes separate from normal feature and bug fix branches.  Delete it once the hot-fix is merged and recreate it as necessary.  Always give it the same name so it can be recognized immediately when there's an outstanding hot-fix.